# Reposition other UIButton after delete one

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, uibutton

I have a code where the user can input several ingredients and can also delete them.

**Method:** input ingredient in searchBar then create UIButton for that input and add into UIView. I also have a function to arrange position of all buttons properly

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {    
    var listInputView = UIView()
    let spacingX: CGFloat = 10
    let spacingY: CGFloat = 10
    let btnHeight: CGFloat = 30
    var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var listBtn = [UIButton]()


    //and also initialization of other components like UISearchBar,...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSegmentControl()
        setupView()

        listInputView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        heightConstraint = listInputView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 10)
    }

    func setupSegmentControl() {
        //setup UISegmentedControl
    }

    fileprivate func setupView() {
        //setup UISearchBar
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        if segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            //search from input menu
        }
        else {
            //search from input ingredients
            inputSearchBar.append(mainSearchBar.text!)
            listIngredients()
        }
    }

    func listIngredients() {
        view.addSubview(listInputView)
        listInputView.isHidden = false

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            listInputView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainSearchBar.bottomAnchor, constant: 10),
            listInputView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            listInputView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),
            heightConstraint
        ])

        createIngredientBtn(ingredient: mainSearchBar.text!)
    }

    // create a button
    func createIngredientBtn(ingredient: String) {
        let deleteIcon = UIImage(systemName: "multiply")
        let btn = UIButton(type: UIButton.ButtonType.custom) as UIButton
        btn.setTitle(ingredient, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(UIColor(hexString: "#707070"),for: UIControl.State.normal)
        btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor(hexString: "#707070").cgColor
        btn.layer.borderWidth = 1.0

        btn.frame.size.height = btnHeight
        btn.layer.masksToBounds = true

        btn.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 8, bottom: 0, right: 8)
        btn.setImage(deleteIcon, for: .normal)
        btn.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        btn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 10, bottom: 0, right: 3)
        btn.semanticContentAttribute = UIApplication.shared.userInterfaceLayoutDirection == .rightToLeft ? .forceLeftToRight : .forceRightToLeft
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteSelectedInput), for: UIControl.Event.touchDown)
        btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        listBtn.append(btn)
        listInputView.addSubview(btn)
    }

    // delete a button
    @objc func deleteSelectedInput(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.removeFromSuperview()
        listBtn = listBtn.filter {$0 != sender}
        showListBtn() //I try to call this here to reposition other buttons
        viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        inputSearchBar = inputSearchBar.filter {$0 != sender.currentTitle}
        if inputSearchBar.isEmpty {
            listInputView.isHidden = true
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        showListBtn()
    }

    //Arrange position of each button and update height of inputView according to them
    func showListBtn() {
        let listInputViewWidth = listInputView.frame.size.width
        var currentOriginX: CGFloat = 0
        var currentOriginY: CGFloat = 0

        listBtn.forEach { btn in
            // break to newline
            if currentOriginX + btn.frame.width > listInputViewWidth {
                currentOriginX = 0
                currentOriginY += btnHeight + spacingY
            }

            // set the btn frame origin
            btn.frame.origin.x = currentOriginX
            btn.frame.origin.y = currentOriginY

            // increment current X
            currentOriginX += btn.frame.width + spacingX
        }

        // update listInputView height
        heightConstraint.constant = currentOriginY + btnHeight
    }
}
```

**Problem:** Suppose I have > 1 input ingredients (> 1 button) and I delete one of it, the rest will be overlapped on each other at the leftmost origin (where 1st button is placed). At this moment, the position of them is actually correct, they just don't re-display as they should be. 
However, when I try to input new ingredient, they will then display properly.

Here is the image to clarify this better:

[Input 3 ingredients: Ing1, Ing2, Ing3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TacgS.png)

[Delete Ing1. Then Ing2 and Ing3 are overlapped at the position of Ing1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSyOP.png)

[Add new input Ing4. They are all position correctly again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XeLtT.png)

Why the buttons are not re-position correctly when I delete one of them and how can I solve this ? Please kindly help me. Thank you.

**EDIT:** I'm able to call viewDidLayoutSubviews after delete but the buttons still not re-draw at new position although the frame.origin has changed correctly.

```
@objc func deleteSelectedInput(_ sender: UIButton) {
        sender.removeFromSuperview()
        listBtn = listBtn.filter {$0 != sender}

        listInputView.removeAllSubviews()
        listBtn.forEach { btn in
            listInputView.addSubview(btn)
        }

        inputSearchBar = inputSearchBar.filter {$0 != sender.currentTitle}
        if inputSearchBar.isEmpty {
            listInputView.isHidden = true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not use UIStackView for listInputView instead? It removes the hassle of working with constraints.

Comment: At first I tried using the stack view, but then I found out that there is no method to break into new row after the elements exceed the frame width so I came back to regular view.

Comment: That's correct. You would handle adding new rows using a combination of horizontal and vertical UIStackView's. You can also have a look at UICollectionView, as it supports wrapping views (cells) automatically once it reaches end of available space.

Comment: I will have a look at it. What about current problem here ? Do you have any idea why this occur ? I'm stuck at this for a day now. Will the collectionView help me out ? :/

Comment: Try commenting the call to viewDidLayoutSubviews() in deleteSelectedInput() method and replace it with listInputView.setNeedsDisplay().

Comment: Not working :/ Still the same problem though.

Comment: Before the call to listInputView.setNeedsDisplay(), iterate through the all the views in listInputView and check if the frame origins are correctly set. Try to debug at each step.

Comment: Well, the frame is correctly set. I have tried input Ing1, Ing2, Ing3 and delete Ing2. 
At first Ing2 frame is (74.3333 0; 67.3333 22) and after I delete it, Ing3 frame is also (74.3333 0; 67.3333 22) which is correct because it will move to position of Ing2.